# Adding metadata to uploaded file on MongoDB Express with Gridfs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I am trying to build an web app where users can upload their resume and send it to recruiters. I am trying to add applicantID as metadata to each uploaded file so it would be easier for the lookup function later. However, metadata doesn't show on the command-line console of mongodb.

I just want to add applicantID so I can do the look up function later. If anyone has a better idea on how I should implement this. I am open to new ideas.

this is the storing engine

```
//creating storing engines
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(URI)
let gfs;
let fileID = ''
conn.once('open',()=>{
  gfs = Grid(conn.db,mongoose.mongo)
  gfs.collection('uploads')
})
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: URI,
    file: (req, file) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          }
          const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
          console.log(fileID)
          const fileInfo = {
            filename: filename,
            bucketName: 'uploads',
            metaData:{
              applicantID: fileID,
              msg: 'Hi there'
            }
          };
          resolve(fileInfo);
        });
      });
    }
  });
const upload = multer({ storage });
```

This is the route where user post the file

```
//@route /submit-application/jobID POST
//This is where users submit the resume file
//Now you need to save this to the database
router.post('/submit-application/:jobID([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})/:applicantID([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})',upload.single('file'), (req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.file)
  res.redirect('/')

})
```

This is a screenshot of a query I ran
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. If you want to add metadata to your file, it needs to be 'metadata' instead of 'metaData'